# How to communicate that creating an account is optional to using the site?

Tags: user-expectation, login, registration

I have a site that can mostly be used without creating an account. Accounts are only needed for things such as preserving favorites across devices, which is minor in the context of the site.

I want to provide forms for users to create accounts, but I don't want login and join buttons and forms on site to imply they need to create an account to use the site, giving users the appearance of friction and causing some to bounce off the site.

How can I best convey in my login and join buttons and forms that accounts are not required for using the site?

Comment: You could add a tooltip or include "(optional)" next to create account button or create account page. Though I doubt that people would create an account unless required.

Comment: Let them do whatever it is you think they can do, until they can't do what they want to do. In short: just let them access everything that doesn't require an account without an account, and lock everything else behind an account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do that. Vice versa: for functions that need login indicate that clearly, e.g. disable corresponding button and show a hint (like a lock) that this button is only available after login.

Comment: Good answer. Disabling instead of hiding functions that require log in is a good idea. I'm confused on "Don't do that.". What does that refer to.